# titlesec section titlespacing not working after clearpage

Tags: spacing, titlesec, clearpage

In my scrreprt styled dcoument, the chapters, sections, etc. are formatted with titlesec. It is configured to insert a `\cleardoublepage` command before a new chapter and a `\clearpage` command before a new section. However, the `\clearpage` command seems to make the `\titlespacing{\section}` unfunctional. I want to increase the spacing between the section title and the top of the page.

I did my best to create a minimum working example that still shows my problem. It seems to be long but I think it only contains relevant information.

```latex
\documentclass[
  11pt,
  a4paper,
  DIV=calc,
  headinclude, footincude,
  headsepline, footsepline,
  twoside,
  openright,
  british
  ]{scrreprt} %scrreprt/scrartcl


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=8mm, left=2.1cm,right=2.1cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\footskip}{11mm}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setlength{\headheight}{17pt}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{setspace}
    \setstretch{1.2}
\usepackage{apptools}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% Chapter def
\newcommand{\chapterbreak}{\cleardoublepage}    
\titleformat{\chapter} % command
    [display] % shape
    {\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont\huge\raggedleft\scshape} % format
    {\filleft\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont
        \IfAppendix{}{\bfseries\large\chaptername}\,\scalebox{5}{\color{lightgray}\thechapter}}%
    {-2ex} % sep between label and title
    {
        \color{darkgray}\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
        \vspace{1ex}
    } % before-code
    %[] %after-code
\titlespacing{\chapter}
    {0pc} %left margin
    {-4ex} %before sep
    {4pc} %after sep

% Section def
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}  % <------- This sets the clearpage before a new section
\titleformat{\section} %command
    [hang] %shape
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries} %format
    {\thesection.}
    {0.5em}
    {}
    %[]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pc}{70px}{70px} %<----------- Here is the problem !!


\begin{document}
\chapter{Chuck Norris}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut 
enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...

\section{First Section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut 
enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...

\section{Second Section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut 
enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...

\chapter{NoAppendix - Normal Chapter}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut 
enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut 
enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that I understood correctly... but in order to use a space after a `\cearpage` you possibly need a `\null` command so that it will "create an initial point" for the upcoming `vspace` in the cleared page:

```
\documentclass[
  11pt,
  a4paper,
  DIV=calc,
  headinclude, footincude,
  headsepline, footsepline,
  twoside,
  openright,
  british
  ]{scrreprt} %scrreprt/scrartcl


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=8mm, left=2.1cm,right=2.1cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\footskip}{11mm}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setlength{\headheight}{17pt}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{setspace}
    \setstretch{1.2}
\usepackage{apptools}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% Chapter def
\newcommand{\chapterbreak}{\cleardoublepage}    
\titleformat{\chapter} % command
    [display] % shape
    {\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont\huge\raggedleft\scshape} % format
    {\filleft\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont
        \IfAppendix{}{\bfseries\large\chaptername}\,\scalebox{5}{\color{lightgray}\thechapter}}%
    {-2ex} % sep between label and title
    {
        \color{darkgray}\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
        \vspace{1ex}
    } % before-code
    %[] %after-code
\titlespacing{\chapter}
    {0pc} %left margin
    {-4ex} %before sep
    {4pc} %after sep

% Section def
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage\null}  % <------- This sets the clearpage before a new section (koleygr: edited)
\titleformat{\section} %command
    [hang] %shape
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries} %format
    {\thesection.}
    {0.5em}
    {}
    %[]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pc}{70px}{70px} %<----------- Here is the problem !!


\begin{document}
\chapter{Chuck Norris}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut 
enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...

\section{First Section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut 
enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...

\section{Second Section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut 
enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...

\chapter{NoAppendix - Normal Chapter}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut 
enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut 
enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi koleygr,
you are genious! Thank you so much! Fiddled around with \mbox but that didn't work. Such a small line of code, such a big effect. Thank you very much! Solved it :-)

Comment: Welcome @FloG ... Happy TeXing!

Comment: @koleygr -- `\null` is the "plain TeX" method (and it does have the desired effect).  For LaTeX, `\vspace*` doesn't disappear at the top of a page, although the dimension specified is most likely different, since `\null` actually inserts an (empty) text line.

Comment: Thanks @barbarabeeton .... But it is easier that modifying titlesec commands... This is why I used this method. (I love plain TeX and still reading the TeXBook... Unfortunately "the Art of computer programming" is not available at all in my country). You are right (of course) about the empty line.... Possibly I should tell to the op to reduce slightly the added space from the command...